# Plotting dataframes using matplotlib in Python IDE

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a dataframe which has been taken from **get_data_yahoo** attribute in **pandas_datareader.data** on python IDE using matplotlib.pyplot and I am getting an KeyError for the X-Co-ordinate in prices.plot no matter what I try. Please help!

I have tried this out :-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pandas import Series,DataFrame

import pandas_datareader.data as pdweb

import datetime

prices=pdweb.get_data_yahoo(['CVX','XOM','BP'],start=datetime.datetime(2020,2,24),
                            end=datetime.datetime(2020,3,20))['Adj Close']

prices.plot(x="Date",y=["CVX","XOM","BP"])
plt.imshow()
plt.show()
```

And I have tried this as well:-

```
prices=DataFrame(prices.to_dict())
prices.plot(x="Timestamp",y=["CVX","XOM","BP"])
plt.imshow()
plt.show()
```

**Please Help...!!**

P.S: I am also getting some kind of warning, please explain about it if you could :)

Comment: Can you post the error and the traceback?

Comment: I am getting a KeyError for the X Co-ordinate in prices.plot

Comment: In that case, what does your DataFrame look like? What are the column names?

Comment: There are a total of 4 columns, the 2nd 3rd and 4th are ["CVX,"XOM","BP"]  respectively. The 1st column is a datetime column, the name of which I am not sure about, so I tried to convert the DataFrame into a dictionary and then see the name...but I am not sure how to explain what I saw there, because I have never seen that kind of a dictionary before.

Comment: Try using print(df.columns) to see.

Comment: I tried that right now, but then only the names of 2,3,4 columns are being shown but not the first. I am taking the first datetime column as my x-axis, but the name of that column isn't visible

Comment: Okay, I see your problem. Alan's answer below should cover the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @LTheriault :)

Comment: Of course! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Date column isn't an actual column when you import the data. It's an index. So just use:

```
prices = prices.reset_index()
```

Before plotting. This will convert the index into a column, and generate a new, integer-labelled index.

Also, in regards to the warnings, Pandas is full of them and they are super annoying! You can turn them off with the standard python library warnings.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Got it! I am really grateful to you! Thank you :) :)